# RoR Test Driven Development - `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, capybara, ubuntu-12.04

I am folowing this tutorial to develop some Ruby on Rails application. http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec-TDD

I have created `..._spec.rb` file.

but when I run command - `bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb`

There is an error - `require: cannot load such file -- nokogiri (LoadError).`

Can anyone help me?

Full error message:

```
/home/karlis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/capybara-2.0.1/lib/capybara.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri (LoadError)
from /home/karlis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/capybara-2.0.1/lib/capybara.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/karlis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /home/karlis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /home/karlis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /home/karlis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
from /home/karlis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /home/karlis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/karlis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
from /home/karlis/workspace/sample_app/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/karlis/workspace/sample_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
from /home/karlis/workspace/sample_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/karlis/workspace/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `require'
from /home/karlis/workspace/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/karlis/workspace/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `require'
from /home/karlis/workspace/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/karlis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:784:in `load'
from /home/karlis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:784:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /home/karlis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:784:in `each'
from /home/karlis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:784:in `load_spec_files'
from /home/karlis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
from /home/karlis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
from /home/karlis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `block in autorun'
```

Comment: Is Nokogiri in your bundle?

Comment: No. The Nokigiri gem wasn't installed... But now I installed it, put it into gemfile, but the gem isn't showing on bundle install

Comment: When I run bundle install - it shows that I am using nokogiri, but still the same error on bundle exec rspec...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this problem is manually updating the capybara bundle, it solved my problem. 
"bundle update capybara"

Comment: This is an issue the occured in capybara 2.0.1 and the root cause is still unknown: (https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/882)
For now, I can confirm that Vincent has the correct workaround.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, if I don't have a Gemfile, the gems are located automatically, but as soon as I made an empty one, I needed to include nokogiri and other gems. Hope this helps.